# How to make Method Reference in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out why I cannot use Method Reference in my example:

```
MyF f = MyF::new;

static class MyF implements F<String, Integer> {
    public Integer fun(String s) {
        return null;
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface 
interface F<T, R> {
    R fun(T t);
}
```

How can I fix my code to make `MyF::new` work?

PS: 
Now I get an error `MyF is not a functional interface`.

Comment: The duplicate explains why what you have is wrong. I still don't understand what you are trying to do with the statement `MyF f = MyF::new;` though. What do you expect that to do? Why do you think so?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how does `Method Reference` work.

Comment: Which part of tutorial/book you are reading makes you think that this code should work?

Comment: [Here's the official tutorial.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

Comment: ClassName::new - Reference to a constructor. In `MyF` I have a default constructor.

Comment: Lets start from lambdas for now. What is it? Where can you use it/assign to?

Comment: Lambda it is an anonymous class. For instance: `interface T { String fun (String s); }` => `T t = (String s) -> s.toLowerCase();` (lambda).

Comment: And what is the type of this anonymous class? How compiler knows it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. And how does compiler know it? Maybe it uses type inference somehow...

Comment: Yes, it is type inference, or simpler type of variable which should hold this lambda. But one condition of which variable can hold lambda is type of that variable and that type needs to be functional interface (interface with only one abstract/not-implemented method) so compiler would know which method lambda is suppose implement.

Comment: But in your case `MyF f = MyF::new;` or to be more precise `MyF f` is `MyF` functional interface?

Comment: No, because it's not abstract.

Comment: And that is what error message is trying to tell you "MyF is not a functional interface" so you can't assign this method reference (or lambda) to `f` variable.

Comment: Also you can't assign lambdas to abstract class. Functional interfaces are only interfaces (not abstract classes).

Comment: Ok, I still don't get it.

Comment: `MyF::new` is lambda which may look like `(arguments) -> return new MyF(arguments)`. In other words it is implementation of some method like `MyF someMethod(arguments);` which should belong to functional interface. So you can use something like `Supplier p = MyF::new`.